# Datatable is not showing up on shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have been using the same code to render `DT::datatable` using shiny but since yesterday it seems not to work. When I fire up the app, my datatable is not shown. However, when I use in in RStudio, it shows the table.

Here is my code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Test', titleWidth = 400),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 400,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("Resources", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "rdb",
                              menuSubItem("Internal", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "rdbi")
                              )
                     )
                   ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "rdbi", 
              datatable(data = read.csv('internal.csv'))
              )
      )
    )
  )
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
})
```

internal.csv

```
Resource,Link
Sample1,Test1
Sample2,Test2
Sample3,Test3
Sample4,Test4
Sample5,Test5
```

When I fire up the app, this is what I see:

[image]

When I use the command in RStudio like this, it works:

```
datatable(data = read.csv('internal.csv'))
```

[image]

Also, this is the error I am getting on my console:

[image]

Here is the sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.4               shinydashboard_0.6.1 shiny_1.0.5         
[4] BiocInstaller_1.28.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15    digest_0.6.15   mime_0.5        R6_2.2.2       
 [5] xtable_1.8-2    jsonlite_1.5    magrittr_1.5    tools_3.4.2    
 [9] htmlwidgets_1.0 crosstalk_1.0.0 httpuv_1.3.5    yaml_2.1.16    
[13] compiler_3.4.2  htmltools_0.3.6
```

Please advise.

**UPDATE**: based on some comments I moved the datatable in server.R like this:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Test', titleWidth = 400),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 400,
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("Resources", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "rdb",
                              menuSubItem("Internal", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "rdbi"),
                              menuSubItem("External", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "rdbe")
                              )
                     )
                   ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "rdbi", 
              DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table1") 
              )
      )
    )
  )
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDT(expr = read.csv(file = 'internal.csv'))

})
```

Why does it show the table even before I click on the sub-menu item `Internal`?

Comment: I might be missing something here but why is **datatable(data = read.csv('internal.csv'))** in your ui and not in your server?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Never saw the usage of `datatable` inside `ui` deocumented anywhere and on my machine your code does not work.

Comment: I have been using this to render small tables and it has worked for me before.

Comment: I have updated my question by moving it to server.R but still facing some issue.

Comment: I don't have access to internal.csv, but using output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(iris) makes the app work

Comment: It did work when I moved it to server.R. Thank you guys. Can one of you move this to an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, I think you have to provide another `menuItem` above Resources. This will work as intended (I use iris to run the code). You can switch from one menu to the other and the content will change accordingly.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Resources", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "rdb", startExpanded = TRUE,
               menuSubItem("Internal", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "rdbi"),
               menuSubItem("External", icon = icon("database"), tabName = "rdbe")
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("dashboard", "Dashboard tab content"),
      tabItem("rdbi", DT::dataTableOutput("table1")),
      tabItem("rdbe", "External tab content")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDT(iris)


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```